# Python word in file change

Tags: python, list, replace, split

I am trying to change the words that are nouns in a text to "noun".
I am having trouble. Here is what I have so far.

```
def noun(file):
    for word in file:
        for ch in word:
            if ch[-1:-3] == "ion" or ch[-1:-3] == "ism" or ch[-1:-3] == "ity":
                word = "noun"
        if file(word-1) == "the" and (file(word+1)=="of" or file(word+1) == "on" 
            word = "noun"
          #  words that appear after the 
        return outfile
```

Any ideas?

Comment: "I am having trouble" is not very descriptive of your problem.  What exactly is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your slices are empty:

```
>>> 'somethingion'[-1:-3]
''
```

because the endpoint lies before the start. You could just use `[-3:]` here:

```
>>> 'somethingion'[-3:]
'ion'
```

But you'd be better of using [`str.endswith()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) instead:

```
ch.endswith(("ion", "ism", "ity"))
```

The function will return `True` if the string ends with any of the 3 given strings.

Not that `ch` is actually a word; if `word` is a string, then `for ch in word` iterates over *individual characters*, and those are never going to end in 3-character strings, being only one character long themselves.

Your attempts to look at the next and previous words are also going to fail; you cannot use a list or file object as a callable, let alone use `file(word - 1)` as a meaningful expression (a string `- 1` fails, as well as `file(...)`).

Instead of looping over the 'word', you could use a regular expression here:

```
import re

nouns = re.compile(r'(?<=\bthe\b)(\s*\w+(?:ion|ism|ity)\s*)(?=\b(?:of|on)\b)')

some_text = nouns.sub(' noun ', some_text)
```

This looks for words ending in your three substrings, but only if preceded by `the` and followed by `of` or `on` and replaces those with `noun`.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> nouns = re.compile(r'(?<=\bthe\b)(\s*\w+(?:ion|ism|ity)\s*)(?=\b(?:of|on)\b)')
>>> nouns.sub(' noun ', 'the scion on the prism of doom')
'the noun on the noun of doom'
```